# Not typical inserting into doubly-linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I got a task I don't know how to 'bite'.

> Write a method , which inserts a pair of nodes in doubly- linked list
>   with keys of type double, before and after each node with a given key
>
> **int insert (double where, double before, double after)**
>
> The function returns number of inserted pairs.

How should I interpret it?
How to implement it?

template<...

Comment: I suppose you are given a `key` and for each `node` in your `list`, where its `key` matches the given one, you have to insert a node with key `before` before it and insert another one with key `after` after it. I.E. for a list of `[1, 2, 3, 2, 0]`, `where = 2`, `before = 11`, `after = 22`, your list should end up looking like `[1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 11, 2, 22, 0]`. Notice that now, each `2` is between the `before` and `after` key

Comment: Make the functions `insertBefore`/`insertAfter` then just go through your list and call those two methods on the appropriate nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int insert (double where, double before, double after);
```

It seems reasonable straightforward. For every key matching `where`, you have to insert `before` before it and `after` after it.

So, let's say you have:

```
||- 1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 2 <-> 2 -||
```

Then the call:

```
quant = insert (2, 3.14, 2.72);
```

would end up modifying the list as follows:

```
||- 1 <-> 3.14 <-> 2 <-> 2.72 <-> 3 <-> 3.14 -+
                                              |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                              
+-> 2 <> 2.72 <> 3.14 <> 2 <> 2.72 -||
```

and returning the value `3`.

Aside from the act of inserting both before and after a node, this is exactly like any other insertion operation, and the fact it's a *doubly* linked list actually makes things easier. The pseudo-code for such a beast would be:

```
# HEAD is pointer to first element, TAIL to last.

# Process entire list, doing the insertions as needed.

def insert(where, before, after):
    count = 0
    curr = HEAD
    while curr != null:
        if curr.data == where:
            count = count + 1
            insertBefore(curr, before)
            insertAfter(curr, after)
            curr = curr.next # see note (a) below.
        curr = curr.next
   return count

# Insert before a node, special processing needed for head.

def insertBefore(curr, value):
    node = new element
    node.data = value
    node.next = curr
    if curr == HEAD:
        HEAD = node
    else:
        curr.prev.next = node

def insertAfter(curr, value):
    node = new element
    node.data = value
    node.next = curr.next
    curr.next = node
    if curr == TAIL:
        TAIL = node
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You *may* be wondering why I advance the pointer *twice* in the case where an insertion happens. This will hopefully become obvious if you think about what happens when both `where` and `after` have the same value (e.g., `7`).

*Without* the extra advancement, you would find a `7` in your list, then insert another `7` immediately after it. Then you would find *that* `7` and again insert another `7` immediately after it. This would go on for quite some time. If you'd like, go ahead and try it, come back when it's finished.

...

Okay, hopefully it didn't take *too* long to realise it wasn't going to stop without some sort of intervention, such as <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> or lack of infinite memory :-)

The advancement ensures that you don't actually process nodes that you're *adding* to the list, only those that were already in it when the process started.

Comment: I would additionally add that it would return `3` and since this is a doubly linked list, the arrows go both ways.